# JTable right-click copy/paste menu to copy cell data on one click

Tags: java, swing, popup, jtable, contextmenu

I created my `JPopupMenu`. It appears on my `JTable` when I right click on a cell. However, I cannot copy the data in the cell unless I first double click and then highlight the data, and then right click anywhere but this current cell to show my popup menu and copy option.

I would like to copy the data in a cell without having to double click on a cell and enter into cell edit mode where I then need to select the data.

How can I do this?

```
popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setName("popupMenu");
menuItemCopy = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
menuItemCopy.setText("Copy");
menuItemCopy.setName("copy");       
popup.add(menuItemCopy);
popup.addSeparator();
menuItemPaste = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
menuItemPaste.setText("Paste");
menuItemPaste.setName("paste");
popup.add(menuItemPaste);
```

Here's the code that I have in my `MouseListener` for my `JTable`, in `mouseReleased()` and `mousePressed()`.

```
if(e.isPopupTrigger())
{
    JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
    int row = source.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
    int column = source.columnAtPoint( e.getPoint() );

    gridView.popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());              
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the value of clicked cell data?

Comment: Please have a look at my post. Let me know if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things...

1. I'm not sure how you expect a `DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction` and `DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction` to work with a `JTable`, these are suppose to be used with `JTextComponents`...
2. The `JTable` will only highlight the row on a left button press (or key board navigation change), a right mouse button click doesn't do this by default.

Now, I wanted to use the `JTable`'s component popup support, but this seems to consume all mouse events once it detects a popup trigger, which makes it (near to) impossible to highlight the row/column on a right mouse click.

Instead, I ended up adding a `highlight` method into my `MouseListener` which highlights the row/column in question and then triggers the popup.

The reason I did it this way, is the `Action`'s associated with copying and pasting have no concept of anything other than the table, so they don't know what row/column was clicked on.

This allows these actions to focus on worrying about the selection alone.

Content is copied directly to the system clipboard via a custom transferable, which maintains the cell's original type, which means you don't need to reconstruct the object when it's pasted.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorEvent;
import java.awt.datatransfer.FlavorListener;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTable100();
    }

    public TestTable100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
                model.addColumn("Type");
                model.addColumn("Column");
                for (File file : new File(System.getProperty("user.home")).listFiles()) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{file, file});
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new FirstCellRenderer());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                final JPopupMenu pm = new JPopupMenu();
                pm.add(new CopyAction(table));
                pm.add(new PasteAction(table));

                table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                            highlightRow(e);
                            doPopup(e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                            highlightRow(e);
                            doPopup(e);
                        }
                    }

                    protected void doPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                        pm.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                    }

                    protected void highlightRow(MouseEvent e) {
                        JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
                        Point point = e.getPoint();
                        int row = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                        int col = table.columnAtPoint(point);

                        table.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
                        table.setColumnSelectionInterval(col, col);
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    }

    public class FirstCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

            File f = (File) value;

            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                            value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            String prefix = f.isDirectory() ? "DIR" : "FILE";
            setText(prefix);

            return this;
        }
    }

    public class CopyAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JTable table;

        public CopyAction(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
            putValue(NAME, "Copy");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            cb.setContents(new CellTransferable(table.getValueAt(row, col)), null);
        }

    }

    public class PasteAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JTable table;

        public PasteAction(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
            putValue(NAME, "Paste");
            final Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            cb.addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener() {
                @Override
                public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {
                    setEnabled(cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR));
                }
            });
            setEnabled(cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

            Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            if (cb.isDataFlavorAvailable(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR)) {
                try {
                    Object value = cb.getData(CellTransferable.CELL_DATA_FLAVOR);
                    table.setValueAt(value, row, col);
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static class CellTransferable implements Transferable {

        public static final DataFlavor CELL_DATA_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor(Object.class, "application/x-cell-value");

        private Object cellValue;

        public CellTransferable(Object cellValue) {
            this.cellValue = cellValue;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[]{CELL_DATA_FLAVOR};
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return CELL_DATA_FLAVOR.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }
            return cellValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try pasting, table.setValueAt(value, row, col) seems to be working, but no data is displayed in the JTable cell where I pasted. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Also, the PASTE option doesn't seem to get Enabled after I've cut or copied. Not sure why.

Comment: Without a runnable example of your code, I have no idea, as my example seems to work...

Answer (score 1):

Here is code by using **`Clipboard`**

Steps to follow:

- Declare some variable to store the current selected row and column index

  ```
  private static int rowIndex;
  private static int columnIndex;
  ```
- Add `ActionListener` on `MenuItem`

  ```
  menuItemCopy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(String.valueOf(table1
                  .getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex)));
          Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
          clpbrd.setContents(stringSelection, null);
      }
  });

  menuItemPaste.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
          try {
              table1.getModel().setValueAt(clpbrd.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor), rowIndex,
                      columnIndex);
          } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Add `MouseListener` on `JTable` to update the value of `rowIndex` and `columnIndex` and finally show the `JPopupMenu`

  ```
  table1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
          if (e.getButton() == 3) {
              rowIndex = table1.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
              columnIndex = table1.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

              popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
          }
      }

  });
  ```

Comment: This won't work. The table rows and columns may be rearranged from their original order in the model. That's why I suggested using `JXTable` in my answer, because it solves this problem.

Comment: @uyuyuy99 As apposed to just using `JTable#getValueAt`, which you've already pointed out, converts the row/column to model context - I fail to see how `JXTable` adds benefit.  Yes, you are right though, this won't work as expected ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, I see what you're saying now. For some reason, I was thinking that `table.getValueAt()` was only a method for `JXTable`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int row = source.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
int column = source.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
Object valueInCell = table.getValueAt(row, column);
```

Simple!

Comment: I think, OP doesn't want to get the value of current mouse location. OP want `copy cell data on one click`. where is code of setting copied cell data in clipboard.

Comment: @Braj I'm assuming he knows how to copy text to the clipboard... he even shows his own code which already accomplishes this. You say he "doesn't want to get the value of current mouse location," and that he instead wants to copy the cell data -- aren't those essentially the same thing?...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Er, yeah, I didn't forget that. That's why I suggested using `JXTable`. Are you sure you didn't mean to comment on Braj's answer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `table.getValueAt()` is different than `table.getModel().getValueAt()`

Comment: @uyuyuy99 Yes, I'm aware of that

Comment: @uyuyuy99 I miss read you answer, as I had a two year who wanted to spin on my chair, play with mouse and do "comuter" work...:P